# How can I find out the GPT-4 model version when using openai Python library and Azure OpenAI?

Tags: python, version, openai-api, azure-openai, gpt-4

I use GPT-4 via `openai` Python library and Azure OpenAI. How can I find out the GPT-4 model version by using the `openai` Python library (and not looking at https://portal.azure.com/ because for some Azure OpenAI instances I only have the credentials to use the API but I can't view them on https://portal.azure.com/)?

I read:

https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/continuous-model-upgrades:

> You can verify this by looking at the response object after sending a request. The response will include the specific model version used (e.g. gpt-3.5-turbo-0613).

https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-4-and-gpt-4-turbo:

> gpt-4 currently points to `gpt-4-0613`.

---

However, I tried calling gpt-4 version 0314 and gpt-4 version 0125-preview: for both of them, the response object after sending a request only contains `gpt-4`:

```py
ChatCompletion(
    id='chatcmpl-8slN5Cbbsdf16s51sdf8yZpRXZM1R', 
    choices=[
        Choice(
            finish_reason='stop', 
            index=0, 
            logprobs=None, 
            message=ChatCompletionMessage(
                content='blahblah', 
                role='assistant', 
                function_call=None, 
                tool_calls=None
            ), 
            content_filter_results={
                'hate': {'filtered': False, 'severity': 'safe'}, 
                'self_harm': {'filtered': False, 'severity': 'safe'}, 
                'sexual': {'filtered': False, 'severity': 'safe'}, 
                'violence': {'filtered': False, 'severity': 'safe'}
            }
        )
    ], 
    created=1708062499, 
    model='gpt-4', 
    object='chat.completion', 
    system_fingerprint='fp_8absdfsdsfs',
    usage=CompletionUsage(
        completion_tokens=185, 
        prompt_tokens=4482, 
        total_tokens=4667
    ), 
    prompt_filter_results=[
        {
            'prompt_index': 0, 
            'content_filter_results': {
                'hate': {'filtered': False, 'severity': 'safe'}, 
                'self_harm': {'filtered': False, 'severity': 'safe'}, 
                'sexual': {'filtered': False, 'severity': 'safe'}, 
                'violence': {'filtered': False, 'severity': 'safe'}
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

How can I find out the GPT-4 model version when using `openai` Python library and Azure OpenAI?